# Mozilla WebExtensions start page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to make a custom start page in Firefox using WebExtensions.
In Chrome I can set page in manifest.json (chrome_url_overrides), but Firefox doesn't support this feature.
I made it trought `chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener` and `chrome.tabs.update`, but I see the standard home page during the short time until the script processes.
How can I implement it more qualitatively through WebExtensions?

Comment: Firefox should now support overriding newtab page from a webextension. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1234150. I haven't been able to test this though.

Answer (score 1):

The bug to [Support overriding newtab page from a webextension](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1234150) has been resolved and the fix has landed in Firefox 54 (Nightly, as of writing this answer). This means that you can use `chrome_url_overrides` in your `manifest.json` like you usually would. For example:

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Test.",

    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "test.html"
    }
}
```